# Laravel relationship return parent twice

Tags: laravel, model, relationship

I have two model and an One-To-One relation as follow :

```
class Property extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function property()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Property::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

When I want acces **User** from **Property**, I have user's array twice in returned value :

```
$property = Property::where('id', $id)->first();

return response()->json([
                'property' => $property,
                'user' => $property->user
            ], 201);
```

Output :

```
{
    "property":{
        "id":1,
        "name":"test",
        "user":{
            "id":1,
            "name":"arash"
        }
    },
    "user":{
        "id":1,
        "name":"arash"
    }
}
```

What's going one here ? Why There is first user in property ?

Comment: Can you show a) how you query for the `$property` b) the `Property` model

Comment: Question updated ... check first class for `Property` model @devk

Comment: You might want to do this instead: `['property' => $property, 'user' => $property->user()->first()]`. The `$hidden` property works as well, but might cause some unintentional sideeffects later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how serialization works in Laravel.
you can hide it in json

```
class Property extends Model
{
    protected $hidden = ['user'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. i can hide a property by this way ... but why there is a second array in model ?

Comment: its just public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    } from your model.